# How could this be rewritten less imperatively in Rust

Tags: functional-programming, rust

```
fn get_variable_info (route_path: &str) -> HashMap<String, uint> {

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let mut i = 0;
    for matched in REGEX_VAR_SEQ.captures_iter(route_path) {
        map.insert(matched.at(1).to_string(), i);
        i = i + 1;
    }

    map
}
```

I have this function that takes a `&str` and loops through an `Iterator` of captures to produce a `HashMap<String, uint>`. I don't like the imperative fashion of this and wonder if this could be rewritten in a more functional way in Rust?

In pseudo code, something like this would be more what I'm after.

```
let mut i = 0;
REGEX_VAR_SEQ
    .captures_iter(route_path)
    .map(| matched | {
        KeyValuePair{
           key: matched.at(1).to_string(),
           value: i
        }
        i = i + 1;
        KeyValuePair
    })
    .toHashMap()
```

Well, this is still not perfect because I don't like the `i` variable but my first goal would be to get rid of the imperative loop :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re pretty close! Your `KeyValuePair` and `toHashMap` is actually [`Iterator.collect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.collect), which works on the `FromIterator` trait, which `HashMap` implements for `(K, V)` pairs.

Thus, it’s something like `[(k, v), (k, v), (k, v)].move_iter().collect::<HashMap<K, V>>()`.

For the `i` part, there is [`Iterator.enumerate`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.enumerate), which turns `[a, b, c]` into `[(0, a), (1, b), (2, c)]`.

And so this is the end result:

```rust
REGEX_VAR_SEQ.captures_iter(route_path)
             .enumerate()
             .map(|(i, matched)| (matched.at(1).to_string(), i))
             .collect()
```

(You can either leave `HashMap<String, int>` to be inferred if it can be (e.g. a method return type), or specify it on the `collect` call, `.collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()`.)

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot. I should probably name you as a contributor to my Floor project ;-) https://github.com/cburgdorf/Floor

Comment: Thanks's for the extra info! What kind of feature is it that lets me just write `.collect::<HashMap<_, _>>()` instead of `.collect::<HashMap<String, uint>>()`? Both would work just fine. Is this just another form of type inference?

Comment: @Christoph, yes, it is local type inference. As far as I know, it is fairly recent feature of Rust.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: I’m not aware of its being a recently introduced feature, though I only came to know of it in the past couple of months.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, here is its pull request: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/12764. It was introduced in the middle of March. And it is called "partial type hint" in fact.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I missed the fact of its introduction.

Comment: Wouldn't it be (slightly) easier to do `.map(|matched| matched.at(1).to_string()).enumerate()`, or does that fail for some reason (ownership/lifetimes perhaps)?

Comment: @delnan: that would invert the keys and values of the HashMap.